# Query across multiple entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-5

I am trying to do a relatively simple query across entities in EF6 using lambda expressions

My tables look as follows:

```
[Admins] * -- 1 [Doctors] 1 -- * [Patients]
```

I am struggling to query all the Patients for a specific Admin

(Although completely syntactically incorrect) To illustrate what i would like to do is something like this:

```
ent.Patients.Where(p => p.Doctor.Admins.AdminID == 'x');
```

This obviously doesnt work.. in broader terms how can i filter an entity by associated entities using Lambda expressions.

Comment: Did `Any()` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All patients with connected to the Admin "x" using [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
ent.Patients.Where(p => p.Doctor.Admins.Any(a => a.AdminID == 'x'));
```